# do_shortcode showing as a string in post - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a short code `[wtilikepost]` that when added to a post will show a like dislike buttons. But I want to add the short code directly to the my template in the PHP I thought I could just

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[wtilikepost]' ); ?>
```

All that does is output the string "wtilikepost"

Do i need to add something else to my functions.php file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  if( shortcode_exists( 'wtilikepost' ) )
    do_shortcode( '[wtilikepost]' );
  else
    echo "The shortcode <b>wtilikepost</b> is not installed.";
?>
```

This way you will be able to know if it's recognized or installed.